# Swift - NSPredicate

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, nspredicate

Is there a cleaner way to do this without having to specify `searchText` twice? Or is this the best way?

```
let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF.firstName CONTAINS[c] %@ OR SELF.lastName CONTAINS[c] %@", argumentArray: [searchText, searchText])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, I think the va_arg prototype is cleaner than the array one:

```
let searchPredicate2 = NSPredicate(format: "SELF.firstName CONTAINS[c] %@ OR SELF.lastName CONTAINS[c] %@", searchText, searchText)
```

but both case will have the same result, so it's really up to you.

Note you have a third way to create your predicate: using dictionary. Take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSPredicate/predicateWithSubstitutionVariables:).